# Создание csv-файла

Tags: java, csv

Дорогие друзья! Мне надо создать программу, которая будет считывать данные из txt-файла и записывать в csv(csv-файл она также создаёт сама). Я понимаю, как это реализовать, но не знаю, как правильно работать с csv-файлами: какую библиотеку использовать, как создать файл и записывать туда данные. Прошу помочь опытных ребят)) Откликнитесь на мою просьбу, пожалуйста!

Comment: Стандартными инструментами bash

Comment: @misdeed можно подробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть библиотека у apache, называется `commons-csv`. Если собираете свой проект maven, то подключите такую зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Либо скачивайте напрямую [отсюда](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi)

Ниже минимальный пример:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {
    private static final String CSV_FILE = "D:\\test.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (
                BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(CSV_FILE));

                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                        .withHeader("ID", "Name"));
        ) {
            csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "Mikita");
            csvPrinter.printRecord("2", "Tanya");
            csvPrinter.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь этого будет достаточно для старта.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли
Только один вопрос: такой метод ввода записывает в разные столбцы? у меня получается в один

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, Вам надо записывать в один? Или мой код по какой-то причине записывает без разделения? Или может Вы вообще путаете csv с excel? Если вы открываете через excel он и должен быть в один... просто разделен запятыми. Обычно csv смотрят в текстовом редакторе, например, NotePad++.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не до конца была понятна связь между csv и excel. Помогли!

Comment: Ну я к тому, что csv файлы по умолчанию открываются excel и поэтому там выглядит все так, что все записано в одну колонку. Но это не совсем корректная интерпретация. Так или иначе вижу, что Вы уже стартанули дальше)) Рад, что помог.